# SQLite not reading my sql queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the sqllite command line I am executing a sql file as:

```
.read mysquery.sql
```

I am getting the error

```
Error: near line 13: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

The line 13 in my sql file is:

```
SELECT c.kid as name, l.studentID as no
FROM student c, school l, principal b
WHERE c.cname = b.name
```

I cannot seem to figure out where the syntax error is occuring. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess it that the error takes place before line 13, but that the parser can't be sure there's an error until line 13.  Did you forget a semicolon?

Comment: Please how *all* the code *needed* to get the error (but *that's all*). Both DDL and DML. Read about "

How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
".

Comment: My bet goes with missing semicolon in the line 12, too.